# How to compute that n predicates should be true

Tags: logic

Given an arbitrarily big set of predicates {p1 .. pn}. Is there a way to build a rule or set of them to compute a truth value meaning that a number n of predicates have to be true?. So far I can only imagine to make all posible permutations of the valid conjunctions like for n=2 {p1^p2^-p3}, {-p1^p2^p3}, {p1^-p2^p3}.

Comment: You want a formula saying that "exactly $m$ predicates among $n$ given ones are true"?

Comment: This sounds like the unrestricted satisfiability problem, which is the original NP-complete problem by the [Cook-Levin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem)  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ThibautBenjamin yes and RossMillikan yes, It was a homework task consisting on solving a puzzle called HourMaze using Clasp. According to our teacher the method I described above was the way to resolve it but I managed to implement another solution that does not use an exponential number of rules, consisting on implementing a full adder with prepositional logic like this. Carry: (Ci_n ^ Sj_n) -> Ci+1_n+1 Result: ┐(Ci_n <-> Sj_n) -> Sj_n+1.